# Receiving "Invalid 'changeType'" when subscribing to user created event

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create a Webhook (aka Subscription) for users who are `created`, `updated`, or `deleted` in Office 365.

With the `"changeType": "updated"` it works fine but with `"changeType": "created"` it returns an error:

This is the request:

```json
{
    "changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
    "notificationUrl": "https://ourLink",
    "resource": "users",
    "expirationDateTime": "2017-12-16T14:49:57Z",
    "clientState": "pe1g9gqiVsE6KnHTUuK9Tts3o660KOAw9YnavVfKhr22I7FlqC0tfMhpayxrqFP4orFPOjK0rppYtDicvxZosbvOEEgfy3YYoM3FGDwLQiW4MAdSCTdQkffuChjmB"
}
```

Error:

```json
{
    "header": 400,
    "body": {
        "error": {
            "code": "InvalidRequest",
            "message": "Invalid 'changeType' attribute: 'created'.",
            "innerError": {
                "request-id": "74454900-d3df-4962-b58e-cfd7ec7454bc",
                "date": "2017-12-13T16:49:59"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Creating a subscription to a `user` resource is only available in the Beta API 
but according to the documentation, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error message and that the [User Webhook sample application](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/webjobs-webhooks-sample) only handles `updated` and `deleted`, this should be the expected behavior.

I'm also unable to find where in the documentation it states that a `user` resource accepts subscriptions for `created`. If you could provide a link I will make sure the documentation gets updated.

Comment: Ty so much for your quickly reply.

Here are the documents:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/subscription_post_subscriptions

I assumed that all features allowed all changeTypes (created, deleted and updated).

Is there any way to programmatically know when a user has been added to office 365 so that I can also register on our developed platform?

Comment: Could you find the created type?